# What language do the villagers speak in Wrong Turn?

Tags: dialogue, wrong-turn-2021

Could someone identify the language spoken by the members of the sect (or remote village in the woods...) during the trial in *Wrong Turn* (2021)?

Comment: this question seems to just be trivia.  in what way would knowing what language they spoke increase the appreciation or understanding of the movie?

Comment: @DForck42  In the USA, the majority of people speak English as their first language and almost everyone speaks some English. Knowing what language the villagers speak is a clue to the origins of their community.  Indian tribes living along the Appalachian Trail spoke a number of Indian languages known to linguistic historians and often still spoken.  European colonists along the Appalachia Trail would be expected to speak English, Spanish, French, or Dutch. Continued.

Comment: @DForck42  If the villagers don't speak either a known Indian language from the region or one of the four European languges English, Spanish, French, or Dutch, that would be highly unusual and a clue to their origin.  If they spoke Welsh, for example, that would be an indication that nutty theories about Prince madoc and Welsh indians are correct in the fictional universe of Wrong Turn 2021..

Answer (score 3):

It’s Faroese, a dialect of Danish which is found on the Faroe Islands.

According to [fandomize.com](https://www.fandomize.com/featured/bill-sage-on-leading-the-foundation-in-wrong-turn/):

> And in playing the big bad of the film, Bill faced a few challenges when taking on this role. One challenge was the Foundation’s language and the other involved knives.
>
> “The language and dialect came from the Faroe Islands. That dialect came pretty easy but the language is, I mean, I’m actually saying particular words. I’m sure to someone from the Faroe Islands, it makes no sense at all. I love the dialect.”
>
> Now toward the end of the film, Bill has an awesome scene with some knives that was all done in one take.
>
> “It’s a little dance that John does around the table and kills people. And the flip of the knife, it’s harder than flipping a knife because it’s you’re just flipping the handle. Because obviously, we’re not using a knife.”

Comment: Faroese is not a dialect of danish. It is a language that has developed from old norse and is more closely related to icelandic. The people there came from Western Norway. Denmark didn't control the Islands until the end of the middleages and they banned the faroese language for a while. So saying that faroese is a dialect of danish is wildly inaccurate.

Answer (score 2):

I was also intrigued by the language the villagers spoke. At first I thought I heard German words, then it sounded more like a Scandinavian language. Sometimes the names of the characters give away information, so I looked through the credits and found a "Jonhard Mikkelsen" listed as "translator", I googled the name and found an author by that name who wrote a book on the language of the Faroe Islands, which belong to Denmark; it's a language apparently only spoken by several tens of thousand people. Obviously I'm just guessing here, but it sounds like a suitable choice.